# End editing in contenteditable on return key

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I created a html table and set the `td` elements to `contenteditable = true`. If I click somewhere else on the page I "end" the editing of the content which means the cell isn't highlighted anymore and typing characters doesn't add them to the cell.

I want to achieve this on pressing the return key. I already have a key listener to prevent the user from inserting line breaks when pressing the return key:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        event.preventDefault();
        var value = event.target.innerHTML;
        // do something with the value
    }
});
```

How do I "end" editing (something like jump out of the cell) on pressing the return key?

The `td` elements all look like this:

```html
<td class="memory-cell" id="memory-cell-45" data-cell-number="45" width="100" contenteditable="true">0</td>
```

**UPDATE:** I ended up on setting `contenteditable = true` on click and removing the `contenteditable` attribute on return key press.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the `onkeydown` to document or preferably the editable element, and then remove the `contenteditable` property on keydown, if it's the `Enter` key that is pressed.

You can also bind to `document.querySelector(".memory-cell").onkeydown` if youwant to disable it outside div.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.querySelector(".memory-cell").removeAttribute('contenteditable');
  }
}

function enableEditing(element){
  //Adds the content editable property to passed element
  element.setAttribute('contenteditable', true)
  //Focuses the element
  element.focus()
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="memory-cell" onclick="enableEditing(this)" id="memory-cell-45" data-cell-number="45" width="100" contenteditable>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

PS: The additional table element in below snippet was added for reference only

Comment: But I want the user to be able to edit the content again. Removing is not an option.

Comment: Add it again using `.setAttribute('contenteditable', true)` whenever you need to be editable

Comment: @elementzero23 add another event “onclick” on the same element and add the contenteditable attribute then. Also, make a change in your CSS for the td class `cursor: pointer` so that your td elements always look editable.

Comment: I have modified the answer so that editing is re-enabled on double click. Please add to the question too, so future spectators doesn't get confused about why it's there!

Comment: Thank you. I like the idea of a single click to edit, but the first click only makes it editable again and I have to click again to get to the text input. Is there a way to set editable AND enter the text input on a single click?

Comment: OK, I used focus for this.